# Can I use @Singleton or custom scope on any class without @Inject

Tags: android, android-studio, dagger

What will happen if i used @Singleton alone. Because I have learnt that @Singleton or any scope should be used when using constructor injection. But I am not using constructor injection here.
So i wanted to know is the code in this image right.
In this image I am not using @Inject I have only used @Singleton but the code is working fine.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Without `@Inject` annotation on the constructor the class/dependency is simply ignored by dagger, and you would need it in a module somewhere. If supplying by dagger. IMO opinion the only time you should need modules is when you dont have control over a constructor.

Comment: But, since Singleton is a scope, isn't that mean ViewModelProviderFactory instance will exist till its component even if I don't use @Inject on its constructor.